# Combining two data.frames in R using "merge"

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

I have two data.frames The first data frame is as follows:

```
>df1
Names Signal  Transport
dd_1    Y       Y
dd_2    N       N
dd_3    Y       N
dd_4    Y       Y
```

The second data.frame like follows:

```
>df2
Names   Details   Description   Process  
dd_1     nadh        zoll        cytopl
dd_3     mol2        hilt        transport
dd_5     mol3        tamr        secretion  
dd_7     gapdh       lapm        lores
dd_9     kitp        ring-t      N_terminal
```

I would like to combine this two dataframes into a single data frame like this

```
 Names   Details   Description   Process      Signal     Process
    dd_1     nadh        zoll        cytopl        Y           Y 
    dd_2      NA          NA           NA          N           N
    dd_3     mol2        hilt        transport     Y           N
    dd_4      NA          NA           NA          Y           Y
    dd_5     mol3        tamr        secretion     NA          NA
    dd_7     gapdh       lapm        lores         NA          NA 
    dd_9     kitp        ring-t      N_terminal    NA          NA
```

I used the following R-code

```
merge(df1,df2,by="Names",all=T)
```

I tried using merge but it introduced NAs to the entire row though there are values for that particular column. I need merge this two data.frame and introduce NA for those column of the data.frames which doesnt have any value. I got the following output

```
Names   Details   Description   Process      Signal     Process
    dd_1     nadh        zoll        cytopl        Y           Y 
    dd_2      NA          NA           NA          NA          NA
    dd_3     mol2        hilt        transport     Y           N
    dd_4      NA          NA           NA          NA          NA
    dd_5      NA          NA           NA          NA          NA
    dd_7      NA          NA           NA          NA          NA 
    dd_9      NA          NA           NA          NA          NA
```

Kindly guide me

Comment: `na.omit(data.frame)` should work fine

Also, I suggest doing `newDF <- data.frame(oldDF1, oldDF2)`

Comment: @NealC I tried but it didnt work, when I give na.omit(data.frame) it omited the entire row which had NA. I would like to NA for those rows of the column which doesnt value in its data.frame

Comment: Did you try `all = TRUE`?

Comment: @RStudent I tried but it is giving me data frame with NA for the entire row even if there is a value in the second column

Comment: @Thileepan Setting `all = TRUE` (not `all.x`!) I get your desired result.

Comment: Hmm, did you try my second solution?